# Lightmap strange bleeding

Tags: uv

I'm trying to make a Lightmap to use in Unreal Engine and it's producing some weird effects with the lighting. I've tried spacing everything very far apart by scaling everything tiny, increasing the Lightmap resolution, snapping to pixels in Blender... still no go. Can anyone help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does the baked texture itself look like?

Comment: The baked texture of what? The diffuse bake? If that's what you mean, the mesh I have made I am not applying a texture to but instead in this other program am applying a flat white texture to it. I've seen other videos on baking a light map texture based on the scene's light source, but this method doesn't require that as the other program does the lighting internally

Comment: Oh I see. For some reason I thought you said it was baked lighting :P It looks like the artifacts are on the ngons, so maybe that's the problem. Try triangulating the ngons before exporting.